# ffmpeg: zoom over a squared image

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using this command to create a zoom effect over a square image:

```
ffmpeg -r 25 -i image.jpg -filter_complex "scale=-1:10*ih,zoompan=z='min(zoom+0.0015,1.5)':d=125:x='iw/2-(iw/zoom/2)':y='ih/2-(ih/zoom/2)',scale=-1:720"  -y -shortest -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mp4
```

it works great, except the video is not squared at the end, it's a regular 16/9. I tried to play with the scale parameter but the video becomes stuttered every time I change something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `zoompan` filter has an output size option whose default value is 1280x720. So either you'll have to set it manually to the desired size in WxH form, or use the scale2ref filter to resize it back.

Using `zoompan` size option:

```
-vf "scale=-1:10*ih,
 zoompan=z='min(zoom+0.0015,1.5)':d=125:x='iw/2-(iw/zoom/2)':y='ih/2-(ih/zoom/2)':s=WxH"
```

Using `scale2ref` filter:

```
-filter_complex "scale=-1:10*ih,
 zoompan=z='min(zoom+0.0015,1.5)':d=125:x='iw/2-(iw/zoom/2)':y='ih/2-(ih/zoom/2)'[z];
 [z][0]scale2ref[out][ref];[ref]nullsink" -map "[out]"
```

The first is preferable because it avoids multiple scaling operations.

(You don't need the `-r 25` before the image input)